# ACRA : Configured to send report on mail but not getting any mail

Tags: android, acra

I am trying to configure ACRA for the first time. I have followed the Basic Setup guide :

1.Integrated the acra jar file to my app

2.Created a new class extending application class and have added the below code to it :

```
     @ReportsCrashes(formKey = "", // will not be used
     mailTo = "mymailId@gmail.com")
     public class MyApplication extends Application
     {
         @Override
        public void onCreate() 
        {
            super.onCreate();
            ACRA.init(this);
        }
     }
```

3.Made all necessary changes to manifest file

It seems that all is done correctly,I am able to get the below in logcat :

```
12-21 14:59:10.994: D/ACRA(28728): ACRA is enabled for com.android.demo.notepad1, intializing...
12-21 14:59:11.064: D/ACRA(28728): Using default Mail Report Fields
12-21 14:59:11.064: D/ACRA(28728): Looking for error files in /data/data/com.android.demo.notepad1/files
12-21 14:59:11.074: W/ACRA(28728): **com.android.demo.notepad1 reports will be sent by email (if accepted by user).**
```

But I am not able to get any mail :( !

Comment: Hai you got any solution for this problem.

Comment: @Satheesh how to send the crash report to multiple mail IDs?

Comment: @Karthikeyan Use this code above of your application class                                             @ReportsCrashes(formKey = "", mailTo = "a@example.com,b@example.com,c@example.com", mode = ReportingInteractionMode.DIALOG, resToastText = R.string.crash_toast_text, // optional,

        resDialogText = R.string.crash_dialog_text, resDialogIcon = android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info, resDialogTitle = R.string.crash_dialog_title, resDialogCommentPrompt = R.string.crash_dialog_comment_prompt
)

Answer (score 2):

As far i know, the mailTo option needs the user in order to send the email. 
When an error occurs another mail client (such as Gmail.apk) has to be open to process the crash report and send e-mail.  So the error will open a mail client and we need the user to click on send button.

Comment: @Kondra007 You can not automatize sending error with mailTo: feature. mailTo: only send the crash report to another mail app like Gmail. But firstly you should see in the logcat the trace and ACRA trying sendind the error.

Answer (score 1):

Although a bit late, someone might find it useful anyways...

I did have at least a similar problem with ACRA 4.5.0 which I was able to resolve once all the other configuration options were actually set. This means – although partially labeled as optional – I had to give a value to the following options (in the `@ReportsCrashes` annotation)

- `resDialogText = R.string.crash_dialog_text, // Text to display upon crash`
- `resDialogIcon = android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info, //optional (apparently not). default is a warning sign`
- `resDialogTitle = R.string.crash_dialog_title, // optional (apparently not). default is your application name`
- `resDialogCommentPrompt = R.string.crash_dialog_comment_prompt, // optional (apparently not). when defined, adds a user text field input with this text resource as a label`
- `resDialogOkToast = R.string.crash_dialog_ok_toast // optional (apparently not). displays a Toast message when the user accepts to send a report.`

Though I had `mode = ReportingInteractionMode.DIALOG,` set which might be the source of my problems at least.

Comment: It worked just removing `mode = ReportingInteractionMode.DIALOG` and only with `formKey` and `mailTo` parameters ;-)

Answer (score 0):

have not used "mailTo" field ,had only used `@ReportsCrashes(formKey = "formkey")`
Make sure you get the form key from google drive correctly
And on crash you will be getting the report on Google drive excel file
And also make sure you have added Internet permission and Added "MyApplication" in mainfeast

```
<manifest ...>
  <application ... android:name="MyApplication">
    ...
  </application>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET">
  </uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

Detail explanation is provided here http://acra.ch/

Comment: Does not answer the question. Mailing should be another form of bug reporting as it does not require the internet permission. Please see the official ACRA guide: https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/AdvancedUsage#wiki-Sending_reports_by_email